# Building curved objects in R

Tags: r

I want to figure out how to build complex curved lines/polygons in R.  We can easily draw a simple bezier line, e.g.

```
require(grid)
x <- c(0.25, 0.25, 0.75, 0.75)
y <- c(0.25, 0.75, 0.75, 0.25)
grid.newpage()
grid.bezier(x, y)
```

[image]

This method seems scale-constrained to 0-1 in both axes, and I'm not sure how to build beziers in a custom scale.  I'm also unclear how R can bind these bezier objects together into polylines and ultimately polygons.  If anyone can provide a minimal example I'd be very grateful.  But alternatively a point in the right direction of documentation would greatly help, as I've not found a workflow so far.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @geotheory! What types of curves are you drawing? What sort of relationships are there? Any dependent packages? In your example, you used `grid`. How important is that?

Comment: Plotting functions using grid typically do have a range of 0-1 npc which is the default coordinate scale. Look up `?grid::unit`

Comment: @myles-baker I'm just looking to develop slightly more elegant graphs. Doesn't have to be grid if there's an easier way..?

Comment: @geotheory If you could explain what you're trying to model / plot it would be helpful. `grid` is a low-level plotting library and a higher-level plotting library, like `ggplot2` or `matplot` may be more appropriate. If you want really elegant graphs, the value-proposition of a high-level library is huge.

Comment: Yes I use ggplot but it can't deliver in this case, a [longitudinal allivual plot](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8222356/how-to-generate-a-graph-diagram-like-google-analyticss-visitor-flow).  Ggplot's stacked area plot comes close but ranks are fixed and lines straight.  The [alluvial package](http://www.r-bloggers.com/alluvial-diagrams/) also can't handle longitudinal data as far as I can tell.  So I'm trying to figure out how much work to build a function myself..

Comment: Ok, that's fair. I have never created alluvial plots from scratch and I'm sure it's non-trivial. I followed this blog post when I created alluvial plots using R in the past: http://www.r-bloggers.com/alluvial-diagrams/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand `grid.bezier` you will have to chain individuals segments. This can be done via the `id` argument, but see also `?grig.bezier`.

You can adjust the scale through `viewports` and the `xscale` and `yscale`.

```
library(grid)
x <- c(0.2, 0.2, 0.7, 0.4, 0.2, 0.2, 0.4, 0.4)
y <- c(0.2, 0.4, 0.7, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0.2)

grid.newpage()
grid.bezier(x, y, id=rep(1:2, each=4))

grid.newpage()
pushViewport(plotViewport(xscale=c(0, 10), yscale=c(0, 100)))
grid.xaxis()
grid.yaxis()

x <- x * 10
y <- y * 50

grid.bezier(x, y, id=rep(1:2, each=4), default.units="native")
```

Note that I used `dataViewport` which is just a convenience function wrapping `viewport`.

Comment: This is useful thanks. How do you fill the resulting object, e.g. such as.. `x<-c(.2,.6,.4,.8); y<-c(.2,.2,.5,.5); grid.newpage(); pushViewport(plotViewport(xscale=c(0,1), yscale=c(0,1))); grid.xaxis(); grid.yaxis(); grid.bezier(x,y); grid.bezier(x,y+.3); grid.segments(.2,.2,.2,.5); grid.segments(.8,.5,.8,.8)`

Answer (score -1):

If you have the parametrization 'Y' of the curve you want to draw, you could just

```
t <- c(1:1000)*0.001
plot(t,Y(t))
```

or something like that.